# How can I get current location of user (Latitude and Longitude ) using BEACONS in android (kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, geolocation, location, latitude-longitude

I want to find my current location i.e latitude and longitude using beacons in android application

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Beacons don't give latitude and longitude.  They give relative location to the beacons themselves via triangulation.  For example let's say you had 3 beacons in a triangle around you.  If the strength of all 3 beacons is the same, you know you're in the exact center.  If one of them is stronger, you know you're closer to that one.  Using some math you can use the signal strengths to figure out your distance and angle from each beacon.  But that has NOTHING to do with latitude and longitude.  If you knew the exact latitude and longitude of the beacons themselves you could combine your relative distance with the location of the beacon (and more math, because for longitude 1 degree of longitude is bigger or smaller depending on your latitude) to get your latitude and longitude, but you generally wouldn't bother-  the beacon usecase is normally for locating within an enclosed area, for example figuring out what seat someone is at on a resort, or what exhibit in a museum.

Comment: could you share piece of code regarding that